# pandas lag multi-index irregular time series data by number of months

Tags: pandas, time-series, multi-index

I have the following pandas dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'item': ['red','red','red','blue','blue'],
    'dt': pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-01-31', '2018-03-31']),
    's': [3.2, 4.8, 5.1, 5.3, 5.8],
    'r': [1,2,3,4,5],
    't': [7,8,9,10,11],
})
```

which looks like

```
    item    dt          s   r   t
0   red     2018-01-31  3.2 1   7
1   red     2018-02-28  4.8 2   8
2   red     2018-03-31  5.1 3   9
3   blue    2018-01-31  5.3 4   10
4   blue    2018-03-31  5.8 5   11
```

Note that the time points are irregular: "blue" is missing February data. All dates are valid end-of-month dates.

I'd like to add a column which is the "s value from two months ago", ideally something like

```
df['s_lag2m'] = df.set_index(['item','dt'])['s'].shift(2, 'M')
```

and I would get

```
    item    dt          s   r   t   s_lag2m
0   red     2018-01-31  3.2 1   7   NaN
1   red     2018-02-28  4.8 2   8   NaN
2   red     2018-03-31  5.1 3   9   3.2
3   blue    2018-01-31  5.3 4   10  NaN
4   blue    2018-03-31  5.8 5   11  5.3
```

But that doesn't work; it throws `NotImplementedError: Not supported for type MultiIndex`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `reindex` after `set_index` with only dt

```
df['New']=df.set_index(['dt']).groupby('item')['s'].shift(2, 'M').\
             reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['item','dt']])).values
df
   item         dt    s  r   t  New
0   red 2018-01-31  3.2  1   7  NaN
1   red 2018-02-28  4.8  2   8  NaN
2   red 2018-03-31  5.1  3   9  3.2
3  blue 2018-01-31  5.3  4  10  NaN
4  blue 2018-03-31  5.8  5  11  5.3
```

Comment: Wow. That's spectacular. And, as usual with pandas, completely non-intuitive. Thank you.

Comment: @Jonathan yw :-) happy coding